# Can I drill a tiny hole in this window frame?

Tags: windows

The sill is sloped down so the sill collects about a 1/4” of water from the condensation running down. Is it a bad idea to drill a tiny drain hole through the bottom of the frame and then put that shrink wrap over the whole thing?[image]

Comment: Yes that is a bad idea.  You need to find a way to prevent or at least reduce the condensation on the window.  Storm windows on the outside, dehumidifier inside. Drilling a hole just directs the water somewhere where it can cause damage in the long run.